# Getting Skipped for Docker Image while executing "docker compose push" command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have build the images using docker-compose build command
but when I'm trying to use the push command it is skipping all the 3 images.

***docker compose push
[+] Pushing 3/0
✔ server Skipped                                                                                              0.0s
✔ frontend Skipped                                                                                            0.0s
✔ compiler Skipped***

Any idea, what I'm missing here ?

I want to push the docker images created by docker-compose command and then use those in AWS ECR as per this documentation : https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-compose-from-local-to-amazon-ecs/

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], the command you're running, and its output, all in plain text directly in the question?

Comment: sure, Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

You probably just needed to reference the ECR repository for each container in docker-compose file

```
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: django
    restart: always
    image: <aws-account>.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/<ecr-repo>
```